# How do I specify Server Ip address in my Client program?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ip

I'm currently working with TCP/IP Sockets, My client console program has to connect with server which is my PC, If the destination in the client program is specified as a local host it works fine, what I need to get done with is to connecting the client with my server through internet, what I did is looked up for my IP address on http://www.whatismyip.com/  and tried but it didn't work as I think it's a Network Interface IP address, then I altered destination IP address in client program specifically to the address of my computer which I want it to be a server, but that didn't work also.  Here's my code.

```
Ip = (IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.4"));

MyClient.Connect(Ip,6000);
GetStream = MyClient.GetStream();
Console.WriteLine("CONNECTED TO SERVER");
Read = new BinaryReader(GetStream);
Write = new BinaryWriter(GetStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

There 2 things (at least) that you should be aware of:

1. To access your computer from Internet (from the public address, the one you get with whatismyip.com) you need to open the port (6000) at the router, and tell the router to what IP it should forward the incoming connection. You could specified specifics ports or put a DMZ host where all the incoming connections will be routed to that host/PC. Read your router manual to see how that is done.

2. You cannot access your public IP from the inner side of the router (intranet), if you want to connect to your public IP you need to be in another network.

If you have a dynamic IP (is the default) every time the router is powered off and on then, most probably, that IP would change, you need to investigate thru `whatismyip.com` in order to know what IP has been assigned. You could connect to `dyndns.org` and ask for a host name `myhost.mydomain.com` (.es, .fr, etc), and in the router tell the DDNS (Dynamic DNS) to update that host every time the IP changes. In your client program you then connect to `MyClient.Connect("myhost.mydomain.com", 6000);`

Hope I explain myself well enough, anyway, if you have any question let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much.it sounds more then a help. Let me get into confuguration i ll write back to you afterawards